# Iterating through a nested number-keyed json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, recursion

This might be a duplicate, but I've not yet found a solution to my problem, even though I've checked multitudes of other examples of JSON recursive traversion functions.

My json obj looks sort of like the following:

```
var obj = 
{
    "description": [
    {
        "list": [
            {
                "1": "here is text"
            },
            {
                "2": "other text"
            },
            {
                "3": "arbitrary text"
            },
            {
                "4": [
                    {
                        "1": "indented"
                    },
                    {
                        "2": {
                            "1": "indented to second level"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "3": "first indentation level again"
                    },
                    {
                        "4": {
                            "1": "second level again"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "5": "and first level, to wrap things up"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
};
```

Traversing this with something like:

```
function recurTrav (jsonObj) {
    $.each(jsonObj.description[0], function (key, value) {

        $(".testul").append("<li class=" + key + ">" + value + "</li>");

        if (typeof(jsonObj[key] == "object")) {
            recurTrav(jsonObj[key]);
        }
    });
}
recurTrav(obj);
```

Gives me nothing. (Note that this was just to test how I would traverse. I'm stuck, and it's embarrassing.

I guess I would just need a push in the right direction...

What I'm actually looking to do is creating this into a unordered list structure. Where there can be uls inside the main ul.

```
<ul>
    <li>here is text</li>
    <li>other text</li>
    <li>arbitrary text</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>indented</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>indented to second level</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>first indentation level again</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>second level again</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>and first level, to wrap things up</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What are the rules for your traversion? Right now not even iteration like `for` loop because your `jsonObj[key]` doesn't yield something containing `.description` list

Comment: I'm not sure if it is your only problem, but your parenthesis are messed up in your `if` check.  It should be `if (typeof(jsonObj[key]) == "object")`

Comment: @PatrickQ Yeah, sorry, I typed up the code quick and dirty, can confirm that this is not the actual problem. It yields a bunch of objects, which it doesn't traverse.

Comment: If `obj` is the exact structure you want to traverse why not passing `obj.description[0].list` inside `recurTrav()` first? Or iterate over `obj.description` as recurse? And of course fixing `recurTrav()`.

Comment: You will have to modify your `recurTrav` a bit, first to get the right html structure(you can only have `li` tags inside a `ul` tag, `ul>ul` is not allowed, you would have to use `ul>li>ul`) and second to check for arrays in addition to checking for objects.

Comment: @twil I've done that already, I just can't handle wrapping my head around it, it's really weird.

Comment: @tewathia I updated my example HTML with your input, thank you. I haven't used indented lists in a long time, so I just went ahead from memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd handle it slightly differently. First, I'd make `recurTrav()` return DOM tree. In the simpliest case it would be just flat `<ul></ul>`. If it encounters nested list it wraps result for inner recursion in `<li></li>`.

So...

```
function recurTrav(jsonObj) {
    var cont = $('<ul/>');

    $.each(jsonObj, function (key, value) {
        var el = $('<li/>');

        if (typeof(jsonObj[key]) == "object") {
            el.append(recurTrav(value));
        } else {
            el.attr('class', key);
            el.html(value);
        }

        cont.append(el);
    });

    return cont;
}

var dom = recurTrav(jsonObj.description[0].list);
```